# Is it possible to add drag events like dragstart, dragend, dragdrop etc on custom HTML elements in Web Components

Tags: javascript, event-handling, web-component, dom-events, custom-element

I tried to add event listeners for drag and drop on custom elements created in Web components. But it does not fire the events. The component I tried is actually nested inside another component. Any one knows how to solve this?

```
-- Main Element (custom)
  -- Nested Element (custom) Firing events at this level
```

Code is actually a bit long. So I will try to summarize what I want to achieve. My code has many colums and each column has many cards. So I am trying to drag card from one column to other. Here I have a container custom element which holds custom columns element. Custom Colums element holds many custom column elements. Column element holds custom card element.

I am writing listeners for my card and column components

```
   card.addEventListener('dragstart', (e) => {
       dragstart_handler(e);
    });

    card.addEventListener('dragend', (e) => {
        dragend_handler(e);
    })

   function dragstart_handler(ev) {
      ev.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", ev.target.id);
      ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "copy";
   }

   function dragend_handler(ev) {
      ev.dataTransfer.clearData();
   }

   //column
    column.addEventListener('drop', (e) => {
      drop_handler(e,this);
    });

    column.addEventListener('dragover', (e) => {
      dragover_handler(e);
    });

    function dragover_handler(ev) {
      ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move";
    }

    function drop_handler(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
      var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain");
      ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }
```

Comment: Please provide some code

Comment: If your Event fires inside a shadowDOM, you need to add the ``composed:true`` option for your Event to escape the shadowDOM and propagate into the (parent) DOM

Comment: I have updated the question with more details. When I execute this code, I get an error like "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'." Its not getting the card element using the document.getElementById I guess. So is there any way to get the element